# How do you 'catch' Email addresses inside a log file?

Tags: python, terminal, command-line, sys, language-concepts

```
'''
This program is to read through any number of inputs (that is only: .txt files) the user passes through the sys.argv (through the terminal only). The file should only be a .txt file. Which means there is a conditional. Then the program should print those results to the terminal.
'''


import sys


def find_email(line1):
    '''
    We must find the 'email address pattern' that is: username@domainname.domain
    There is only one symbol to help the read file method catch and print those email addresses:
    The @ symbol and then the two ' ' spaces at each end of the email address. 
    when we call from main() we must read the log file containing emails. 
    '''
    line1 = [' ', '@', ' ']
    at_postion = line1.find('@')
    first_place = line1.find(' ', at_postion)
    second_place = line1.find(' ', at_postion)
    return line1[second_place: first_place + 1]


def main():
    '''
    Main for sys argv input and one wrong file conditional.
    '''
    result = []
    results = []
    sys.argv(input('Enter .txt file: '))
    with open('r', sys.argv) as input:
        for result in find_email():
            result.append(results)
        print(result)
        if sys.argv(input('Enter .txt file: ')) == type(str):
            find_email()
        else:
            print("Error, enter .txt files only")
            exit()
    print(results)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Note again: I am only supposed to use string methods to find these spam email addresses in the log file using read file method and print those emails to the terminal. I am also certain that I have not encountered other conditional errors yet, so it is a work in progress. Also not that this is a school assignment.

a) With the correct sys.argv values. Given that a user can enter as much input as they want. Show error messages or usage in case of an error input.

b) Find all email addresses from a given logfile, considering I can enter a different file. DO NOT use any **static** file.

c) Using the code modularity, refactor your code.

I ran the code a few times and rewritten and I am still getting a variety of errors, I am certain that I am not conceptualizing some critical things. Please point out what you think I am missing or not understanding.

Please feel free to point me to some resources that can help me understand the following: 1) code modularity, 2) read file method, 3) anything I got right, and 4) anything I forgot.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). You said this is you're second time posting, so you should have already known that too after reading the rules twice.

Comment: Also, please provide full tracebacks, not the tooltip of your IDE.

Comment: @MichaelM. I know now thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you've said this isn't a school assignment, it reads like a programming exercise, and for that reason, I won't provide a complete answer. However, I will provide a couple of pointers to set you in the right direction.

The first pointer is that you shouldn't be trying to mess with `argv`. `argv` is a `list` whose values are populated based on the arguments provided on the command-line. So, if your command-line looked like this: `some-program.py arg1  arg2 arg3`, then the following would be the contents of `argv`:

```
argv[0] = "some-program.py"
argv[1] = "arg1"
argv[2] = "arg2"
argv[3] = "arg3"
```

The second pointer I'll provide is that you have the arguments flipped for the `open` call. The file name should be the first argument, and I generally will specify the `mode` parameter explicitly, like so: `open("some_file.txt", mode = "r")`

You cannot use `input` as a variable name, as you're trying to do in `with open('r', sys.argv) as input`, as `input` is a reserved word regardless of where you put it.

You also don't have any logic to read things from the file. My suggestion would be to use the `readline()` method, like so:

```
with open("some_file.txt", mode = "r") as the_file:
    while ( (line := the_file.readline() ) != "" ):
        fields = line.split()
        print("The new line is: %s" % line)
        print("The line's fields are: %s" % str(fields) )
```

(Note that the [walrus operator](https://realpython.com/python-walrus-operator/) `:=` only works with python >= 3.8)

The above snippet opens a file called `"some_file.txt"` and creates a file handle for it: `the_file`. Then, each line of the file is read and stored in `line`. The first statement in the `while` loop body splits the line into fields based on whitespace**. The contents of `line` are then printed out with the first `print` statement, and the contents of the `fields` list are printed out with the second. When `line == ""`, the file has been exhausted and the loop ends.

**For instance, if `line == "something@hotmail.com is an email"`, then `fields` would consist of the following:

```
fields[0] = "something@hotmail.com"
fields[1] = "is"
fields[2] = "an"
fields[3] = "email"
```

As for picking out the email addresses, were you not restricted by the "I am only supposed to use string methods", I'd honestly prefer using [regular expressions](https://www.regular-expressions.info) to capture things like this. However, from the docstring in the `find_email` function, there are three tokens that are consistent across all emails:

1. One `@`
2. One `.`
3. Two `' '`s at the end

At a high level, here's how I would approach this:

1. Use the `find` method to check whether `@` and `.` exist in the string
2. If they both exist, check whether the `@` appears before `.`
3. Check whether the last two characters of the string are `' '` and `' '`.

If all three checks pass, then you can print out the original string.

Regarding code modularity, the `find_email` method is a good example of that. If you're writing a snippet of code that could potentially be reused in another context or could potentially be executed multiple times, wrap it in a function. Not only does this improve the readability of your code, but it also makes debugging tremendously easier.

Hopefully the above items are of some use. Feel free to leave a comment if you have a question.